# Convert a dictionary of a list of dictionaries to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I pulled a list of historical option price of AAPL from the RobinHoood function `robin_stocks.get_option_historicals()`. The data was returned in a form of dictional of list of dictionary as shown below.

I am having difficulties to convert the below object (named `historicalData`) into a `DataFrame`.  Can someone please help?

```
historicalData = {'data_points': [{'begins_at': '2020-10-05T13:30:00Z',
   'open_price': '1.430000',
   'close_price': '1.430000',
   'high_price': '1.430000',
   'low_price': '1.430000',
   'volume': 0,
   'session': 'reg',
   'interpolated': False},
{'begins_at': '2020-10-05T13:40:00Z',
   'open_price': '1.430000',
   'close_price': '1.340000',
   'high_price': '1.440000',
   'low_price': '1.320000',
   'volume': 0,
   'session': 'reg',
   'interpolated': False}],
'open_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
'open_price': '0.000000',
'previous_close_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
'previous_close_price': '0.000000',
'interval': '10minute',
'span': 'week',
'bounds': 'regular',
'id': '22b49380-8c50-4c76-8fb1-a4d06058f91e',
'instrument': 'https://api.robinhood.com/options/instruments/22b49380-8c50-4c76-8fb1-a4d06058f91e/'}
```

I tried the below code code but that didn't help:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(historicalData)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write that you want **only** *data_points* (as in the
other answer), so I assume that you want your **whole** dictionary
converted to a DataFrame.

To do it, start with your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(historicalData)
```

It creates a DataFrame, with *data_points* "exploded" to
consecutive rows, but they are still dictionaries.

Then rename *open_price* column to *open_price_all*:

```
df.rename(columns={'open_price': 'open_price_all'}, inplace=True)
```

The reason is to avoid duplicated column names after *join*
to be performed soon (*data_points* contain also *open_price*
attribute and I want the corresponding column from *data_points*
to "inherit" this name).

The next step is to create a temporary DataFrame - a split of
dictionaries in *data_points* to individual columns:

```
wrk = df.data_points.apply(pd.Series)
```

Print *wrk* to see the result.

And the last step is to join *df* with *wrk* and drop
*data_points* column (not needed any more, since it was
split into separate columns):

```
result = df.join(wrk).drop(columns=['data_points'])
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this fully answers my question. And if fact, the step with wrk was all I was trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to solve with the below. I have chucked the dataframe to a list via list comprehension

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(dic.items(), columns=['Parameters', 'Value']) for dic in historicalData['data_points']]
```

You then could do:

```
df_list[0]
```

which will yield

```
     Parameters                 Value
0     begins_at  2020-10-05T13:30:00Z
1    open_price              1.430000
2   close_price              1.430000
3    high_price              1.430000
4     low_price              1.430000
5        volume                     0
6       session                   reg
7  interpolated                 False
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your promptness, My intent is to sow begins_at, open_price, close_price, high_price, volume, session, interpolated and the columns of my DataFrame. The above code doesn't seem to do that. Is there another code I can use?